# Convert OBJECT to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, .net, colors

I know there are many ways to convert colors in C#, everything from converting strings to Color values, HTML conversion, and even XNA framework; however, I have a object that returns a type of System.Drawing.Color; but as it's an 'object', and not a 'color', i can't seem to use the normal color commands on it.

```
public void SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        _PropertyValues[propertyName] = value;
        Console.WriteLine("Setting Property: {0}={1}", propertyName, value);
    }
```

The above is what happens when a user changes a value on the property Grid in C#.  The results are below:

**Known Names**

> Setting Property: Color=Color
> [DimGray]

**Custom Color**

> Setting Property: Color=Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=128]

**System Color**

> Setting Property: Color=Color [ControlText]

I would like to take the values it has there, and actually convert it to a color, so that I can have it in a defaultColor variable, which was created previously in the program.

However, as it's an **object** and not an actual 'System.Drawing.Color', i can't use things like:

> .ToKnownColor()
>
> .ToArgb()
>
> .ToName()

and so on.

I know that there has to be a way to convert from the object to an actual color.  I do the value.GetType() and it returns **System.Drawing.Color**, so the system knows it's a color, but for the life of me i can't seem to manipulate it.

I'm not an expert at C# yet, so sorry if this sounds so basic, but i'd still like some help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast it to `Color`:

```
var effectiveColor = (System.Drawing.Color)value;
```

This thing in brackets is an [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), where you tell the compiler that you know better and that an actual type of a variable is something else.

Comment: Awesome, and thank you for the quick reply.  Sorry for being such a dolt sometimes :(.  Why does this work by the way?  I've not seen annotation like this, very often, so i'm not quite sure why that works.

Comment: haha, thanks so much for the answer there; i like how you described why it works lol.  This will come in quite handy. :)

Answer (score 3):

The object really is a `Color`, it's just being referenced by an Object reference. So all you need to do is cast it to a Color.

```
Color myColor = (Color)value;
// now you can do all color operations on myColor
```

Comment: Thank you very much; i'm still new when it comes to C# some some of these things i'm not quite aware of yet :)

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to cast the `object` to a `Color`, if that's all it is:

```
Color color = (Color)value;
```