# C# Casting object to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, casting, system.drawing.color

I am trying to convert a color setting that is read from a registry key into System.Drawing.Color. I am casting the object that is returned from the registry to System.Drawing.Color, following this article: [Convert OBJECT to System.Drawing.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705050/convert-object-to-system-drawing-color)

```
System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)result;
```

Here are a couple of examples of these registry values that I am getting as an object:

```
Type     Data
REG_SZ   Color [Olive]
REG_SZ   Color [A=255, R=255, G=128, B=128]
```

Casting the first registry key to System.Drawing.Color works fine, but when casting the second key, I get a "Specified cast is not valid" error. What is the best way to be able to cast both of these keys as System.Drawing.Color?

**EDIT:** I think the easiest way to solve this is when writing to the registry, I convert the Color to an ARGB (int32), that way when I read it I can just use `Color.FromArgb` (unless there is another solution I'm completely missing).

Comment: How about `System.Drawing.Color.FromName(result);`

Comment: or `FromArgb(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It is not the same as the linked Q+A, it used reflection and it actually returned a boxed Color.  But here it is just a plain string.  "Olive [Olive]" certainly cannot be cast either.  You must use ColorConverter.

Comment: The linked question is about a `Color` instance being stored in a parameter of type `object`, in which case a cast is appropriate to be able to access its `Color` members.  In your case you have two `string` instances and there is no way to _cast_ them to `Color`; convert yes, cast no.  Also, you're sure casting the first value works fine?  I can't reproduce that.  `string text = "Color [Olive]"; Color color = (Color) text;` is a compile-time error and `object text = "Color [Olive]"; Color color = (Color) text;` causes the same `Specified cast is not valid` run-time error, as expected.

Comment: @BACON - Sorry, I should have added this in the question. We are reading the registry setting using a helper function which calls RegistryKey.GetValue(string name, object defaultValue), which returns an object. In this example, when debugging, the object returned is "Color [A=255, R=255, G=128, B=128]", so I figured I should be able to cast that to a Color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting from the registry could be a string so use ColorConverter class as suggested from this [page](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/230712-how-read-color-registry)

Here is a sample code:

```
Color regColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString((string)result);
```

Comment: It's good to include some code showing how to use ColorConverter rather than relying on an external link (which is subject to break).

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, I'm getting an exception "Color [A=255 is not a valid value for Int32." The inner exception is "Input string was not in a correct format." The input string is "Color [A=255, R=255, G=128, B=128]".

Comment: I tried it and it seems ColorConverter is not a static class. So correct usage would be `Color regColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString((string)result);`